# CountDistinct with SSRS

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Hey guys i have a report I am writing that is pulling trucks, order numbers, and charges from different tables. I am running into a problem when it pulls more than one truck for the same order it doubles or triples the price. My plan to resolve this is to write an expression to calculate the charge that goes along the lines of `Fields!amount.value / CountDistict(truckColumn)` But it is not working and I am not sure of the best route to take from there of if this is the best solution. Any help would be great.

Comment: are you able to manipulate the data source on the server (i.e. create a new `procedure / view` etc, or are you limited to SSRS

Comment: I can not manipulate the data :(

Comment: Can you show us the tables that you are pulling from. Divide by truck count sounds like you are fixing one problem but you will cause others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you tried writing it as this:

```
=Fields!amount.value/(COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!TruckColumn.Value))
```